# Retrieving values in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I was going through population dataset in googleVis library.Now i am stroring the data in data2

data2 <-data.frame(Poulation)

when i do the following

> names(data2)

the following comes

> [1] "Rank"                   "Country"                "Population"
>   [4] "X..of.World.Population" "Flag"                   "Mode"
>   [7] "Date

Now i want to know the names of the country whose population is greater than suppose 10,000,000

I am trying the following for getting the poulation

data2$Population > 10000000

Now how to get the name of countries which have poulation >10000000

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 data2[data2$Population > 10000000, ]$Country
```